# NaN in SSRS Pie Chart Legend

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have a Pie Chart report that works well until we discovered that when values are `0%` or less across the chart, the Legend returns `NaN`. How do I format the Legend to return `0%` instead of the `NaN` that Users do not want to see. Below is my express for the Legend Property

```
    ="#AXISLABEL" & " - " & "#PERCENT{P0}"
```

Comment: Q1. What is less than 0%? Q2. How you are getting NaN display it in a table? Q3. Are you dividing by zero?

Comment: Thanks Anup. It's a divide by zero error. I had an expression like so:

     `=Fields!Cal1.Value/IIF(Sum(Fields!Cal1.Value, "dsVa") =0,1,Sum(Fields!Cal1.Value, "dsVa"))`

But I still keep getting the error. What can I do?

Comment: 1. Can you provide a sample dataset? 2. Also why you are doing calculation, if you pull the Fields!Cal1.Value on the pie chart SSRS will calculate the percentages for you.

Comment: I finally got it fixed - `=IIf(Fields!value.value > 0, "#AXISLABEL" & " - " & "#PERCENT{P0}", "0%")`